# How do I prevent EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION crashing the XCode simulator 16.4 when attempting to draw an image on a PDF but works on hardware?

Tags: objective-c

The simulator is running iPad Pro (12.9-inch) 6th Generation iOS 16.4. A colleague is running the same iOS version on an unknown device also simulated with the same issue.

The same iPad Pro (12.9-inch) 6th Generation simulator but iOS 13.7 **does** work.

I am getting `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)` on the line where I attempt to draw an image when I run it on the emulator, but it runs as expected when I run it on a hardware iPhone 12 Pro on the same iOS version (16.4). It also runs on a hardware iPad mini 5.

I have tried:

- `CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, image)`
- `[image drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(x, y)];`
- variations such as `[image drawInRect`...

Image, context/currentContext, and rect are all valid, no values are decimal, the sizes fit inside of each other correctly, and it's being ran on the UI thread as it should. This is confirmed by the fact it runs fine on hardware 16.4 and simulator 13.7.

Comment: No one can help if you don't show relevant code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround I found is to first draw the image using a format that is opaque and uses a standard color range and then draw that new image in the PDF context.

```swift
let image = ...

// Re-draw image to adjust color range etc.
let format = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat.default()
format.preferredRange = .standard
format.opaque = true
format.scale = 1 // non-retina
let newImage = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: image.size, format: format).image { _ in
    image.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: image.size))
}

// Draw in PDF context
newImage.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: newImage.size))
```